# joining table causes exponential increase in query time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

my query has been running for 30 minutes so far:

```
SELECT 
   d.accn_id,
   cast(d.load_date as DATE) as LoadDate,
   cast (d.final_rpt_date as DATE) as FinalReportDate,
   sum(p.paid_amt) as SumPaidAmt,
   payors.PAYOR_ID
FROM accn_demographics d
    JOIN accn_payments p
        ON d.ACCN_ID=p.ACCN_ID    
    JOIN accn_payors payors
        ON payors.X_PAYOR_ID=p.X_PAYMENT_PAYOR_ID
WHERE
      p.POSTED = 'y'
  AND p.PMT_DATE between '20120401' and '20120430'    
GROUP BY
    d.accn_id,
    d.load_date,
    d.final_rpt_date,
    payors.PAYOR_ID
```

before i add this table:

```
accn_payors
```

the query took a few minutes, but after adding this table, i am still waiting after 30 minutes.

here are the 3 tables:

```
USE [zzzDataEOMTestingApril]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[accn_payors]    Script Date: 08/20/2012 13:28:20 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[accn_payors](
    [ACCN_ID] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PAYOR_PRIORITY] [int] NULL,
    [PAYOR_ID] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [PAYOR_NAME] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [GROUP_ID] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PLAN_ID] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [SUBSCRIBER_ID] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [INSURED_RELATIONSHIP] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [INSURED_L_NAME] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [INSURED_F_NAME] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [INSURED_HOME_PHN] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [INSURED_WORK_PHN] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [INSURED_ADDR1] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [INSURED_ADDR2] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [INSURED_CITY] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [INSURED_STATE] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [INSURED_ZIPCODE] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [PAID_IN_FULL] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [CLAIM_COMMENT] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [OTHER_INFO1] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [OTHER_INFO2] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [OTHER_INFO3] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [OTHER_INFO4] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [INTERNAL_NOTES] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [SYSTEM_ADDED_PAYOR] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [ELIG_OK] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [ELIG_STATUS] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [ELIG_SERVICE] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [ELIG_VERIF_ID] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [AUD_REC_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [INSURED_DOB] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [INSURED_SEX] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [EMPLOYER_NAME] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [EMPLOYER_ADDR1] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [EMPLOYER_ADDR2] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [EMPLOYER_CITY] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [EMPLOYER_STATE] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [EMPLOYER_ZIPCODE] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [EMPLOYER_COUNTRY] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [EMPLOYER_PHONE] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [EMPLOYMENT_STATUS] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [GROUP_NAME] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [X_PAYOR_ID] [int] NULL,
    [AUDIT_DATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OCCURRENCE_CODE] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [INSURED_SSN] [int] NULL,
    [OCCURRENCE_CODE_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [DELAY_REASON_CODE] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [CASE_ID] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [PAYOR_CODE_TYPE] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [AUTH_NUM] [varchar](40) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_accn_payors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AUD_REC_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


USE [zzzDataEOMTestingApril]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[accn_payments]    Script Date: 08/20/2012 13:28:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[accn_payments](
    [ACCN_ID] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PMT_SEQUENCE] [int] NULL,
    [DEPOSIT_ID] [int] NULL,
    [DEPOSIT_BATCH_ID] [int] NULL,
    [DEPOSIT_BATCH_SEQ] [int] NULL,
    [PROC_CODE] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PMT_TYPE] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [USER_ID] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [NOTE] [varchar](4000) NULL,
    [PMT_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [CHECK_NUM] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [RECEIPT_NUM] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [ALLOWED_AMT] [float] NULL,
    [DEDUCT_AMT] [float] NULL,
    [PAID_AMT] [float] NULL,
    [COPAY_AMT] [float] NULL,
    [POSTED] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [BULK] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [UNITS_PAID] [int] NULL,
    [BILL_AMT_FROM_EOB] [float] NULL,
    [PAYMENT_PAYOR_ID] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [PRICED_PAYOR_ID] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [AUD_REC_ID] [int] NULL,
    [X_ACCN_BILLED_PROCEDURE_ID] [int] NULL,
    [X_PRICED_PAYOR_ID] [int] NULL,
    [X_PAYMENT_PAYOR_ID] [int] NULL,
    [CLIENT_PRIMARY_FACILITY_ID] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [REMIT_FILE_NAME] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [BATCH_POSTED] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [DEPOSIT_POSTED] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [AUDIT_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [ACCEPT_ASSIGNMENT] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [EXPECT_PRICE_DISCREPENCY_AMT] [float] NULL,
    [PRINT_NOTE] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [PATIENT_RESP_AMT] [float] NULL,
    [EOB] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [ICN] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [DEPOSIT_NOTE] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [NETWORK_ID] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [USE_EXPECT_PRICE] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [CO_INS_AMT] [float] NULL,
    [REMIT_DATE] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


USE [zzzDataEOMTestingApril]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[accn_demographics]    Script Date: 08/20/2012 13:28:48 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[accn_demographics](
    [ACCN_ID] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [STATUS] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [CLIENT_ID] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [CLIENT_NAME] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [REQ_ID] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [DOS] [datetime] NULL,
    [SEX] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [PT_ID] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [ORDERING UPIN] [bit] NULL,
    [PT_L_NAME] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PT_F_NAME] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PT_AGE] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [DOB] [date] NULL,
    [PT_HOME_PHM] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PT_WORK_PHN] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PT_ADDR1] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [PT_ADDR2] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [PT_ZIPCODE] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [PT_CITY] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [PT_ST_ID] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [PT_SSN] [int] NULL,
    [RECEIPT_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [INDIGENT_PCT] [float] NULL,
    [PRICE_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [EXPECT_PRICE] [float] NULL,
    [BILL_PRICE] [float] NULL,
    [GROSS_PRICE] [float] NULL,
    [DUE_AMT] [float] NULL,
    [ACCOUNTING_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [FINAL_RPT_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [TIME_OF_SERVICE] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [NO_CHARGE] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [AUD_REC_ID] [int] NULL,
    [ORIGINAL_ACCOUNTING_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [PT_COUNTRY] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PHLEB_FACILITY] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [FASTING_TYPE] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PT_LOCATION] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PHLEB_USER_ID] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PRIMARY_CLIENT_ID] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [PHYSICIAN_SOF] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [PATIENT_SOF] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [STAT] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [CALLBACK] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [PT_REPORT_COPY] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [PT_EMAIL] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PAID_IN_FULL] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [CLIENT_STATEMENT_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [RETRO_BILL_PRICE] [float] NULL,
    [PATIENT_TYPE] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [REFERRING_UPIN] [bit] NULL,
    [PRIMARY_UPIN] [bit] NULL,
    [LOAD_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [TRIP_STOPS] [int] NULL,
    [TRIP_MILES] [int] NULL,
    [ROUND_TRIP] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [TRIP_PATIENT_COUNT] [int] NULL,
    [ADMISSION_SOURCE] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [EMERGENCY] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [ACCIDENT_CAUSE] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PATIENT_MARITAL_STATUS] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [ADMISSION_TYPE] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [PATIENT_STATUS] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [WORPCOMP_CASE_WORKER] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [MRO] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [X_CLIENT_ID] [int] NULL,
    [X_PRIMARY_CLIENT_ID] [int] NULL,
    [AUDIT_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [ORDERING_NPI] [bit] NULL,
    [REFERRING_NPI] [bit] NULL,
    [PRIMARY_NPI] [bit] NULL,
    [CLIENT_PRODUCT] [int] NULL,
    [ONSET_DATE] [date] NULL,
    [ONSET_TYPE] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ACCIDENT_STATE_ID] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [TRADE_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT] [float] NULL,
    [RETRO_TRADE_DISC_AMT] [float] NULL,
    [PATIENT_PREGNANT] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [PATIENT_GRAVIDA] [int] NULL,
    [ORDERING_PHYS_NAME] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [X_ORDERING_PHYS_ID] [int] NULL,
    [REFERRING_PHYS_NAME] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [X_ REFERRING_PHYS_ID] [int] NULL,
    [PRIMARY_PHYS_NAME] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [X_ PRIMARY _PHYS_ID] [int] NULL,
    [ADMISSION_DT] [date] NULL,
    [ADMISSION_TIME] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [DISCHARGE_DT] [date] NULL,
    [DISCHARGE_TIME] [varchar](5) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

**question** how can i speed up this query? are there some indexes that i am missing? why would adding just one table exponentially increase the time it takes to return results for this query? perhaps i should change some datatypes?

Comment: Do you have indexes `accn_payors.X_PAYOR_ID` and `accn_payments.X_PAYMENT_PAYOR_ID`?

Comment: What other indexes do you have?

Comment: @FionaT i have indexes only on accn_payors.X_PAYOR_ID and accn_payments.X_PAYMENT_PAYOR_ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the join to payor is correct?  The payors table has an accnid in it, as well as the payor id.

Try changing your join condition to something like:

```
join accn_payors payors
     on  payors.X_PAYOR_ID=p.X_PAYMENT_PAYOR_ID and
        payors.ACCN_ID = p.ACCN_ID
```

Is there another table with the payor information independent of the account?

Answer (score 1):

Add and index on column `accn_payors.X_PAYOR_ID` and add `accn_payors.PAYOR_ID` to the "included columns" on that index. Also add an index on column `accn_payments.X_PAYMENT_PAYOR_ID`

Comment: Wouldn't doing a subquery on the range of p first help speed up the query as well?

Comment: @CBredlow can you please suggest that in an answer?

Comment: i am following what you said with the included columns right now

Answer (score 1):

Indexing your foreign keys would definitely help - in this case an index on 
accn_payors.X_PAYOR_ID should make the difference.

What volume of data is in your tables?

Comment: thank you. yes i do have that index. each table has about 15m records

Comment: Consider indexes on:accn_payments.PMT_DATE, 
accn_payors.X_PAYOR_ID,
demographics.ACCN_ID

Comment: when i added the accn_payors table, thats when the query took too long, the other tables were quick. does that still mean i should add the indexes to the other tables?

Comment: It's difficult to be sure without seeing the execution plan, but an index on the field you are filtering on (PMT_DATE) should significantly reduce the number of records being matched.  Try it and see if it helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Below

```
Select 
    sum(p.paid_amt) as SumPaidAmt,
    p.ACCN_ID,
    p.X_PAYMENT_PAYOR_ID,
    cast(d.load_date as DATE) as LoadDate,
    cast (d.final_rpt_date as DATE) as FinalReportDate,
From
(
    SELECT     
            p.paid_amt,
            p.ACCN_ID,
            p.X_PAYMENT_PAYOR_ID
    From    accn_payments p
    Where   p.POSTED = 'y'
    AND     p.PMT_DATE between '20120401' and '20120430'    
)p
INNER Join accn_demographics    d           ON d.ACCN_ID=p.ACCN_ID
JOIN accn_payors                payors      ON payors.X_PAYOR_ID=p.X_PAYMENT_PAYOR_ID
GROUP BY
    d.accn_id,
    d.load_date,
    d.final_rpt_date,
    payors.PAYOR_ID
```

Comment: thank yo uso much for your time. what is the reason you used INNER JOIN and JOIN , since they mean the same thing?

Comment: They function the same. INNER JOIN can be a bit more clear to read, especially if your query has other join types (e.g. LEFT or RIGHT) included in it. Inner is optional. Similarly with OUTER JOINs the word "OUTER" is optional, its the LEFT or RIGHT keyword that makes the JOIN an "OUTER" JOIN. Check her for more details http://dbaspot.com/sqlserver-faq/268080-join-vs-inner-join.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at query execution planned in SQL Management Studio? It sometimes provides the tips about missing indexes.